# How to print formatted text as forum's description with nicEdit javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nicedit, dotproject

I have a problem with nicEdit script. It works nice, you can edit your text, but the problem is when I post message to a forum it looks like encoded html text. I am thinking I should decode somehow. Am I wrong?

There is my code how I use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        new nicEditor().panelInstance('message_body');
  });
  </script>

<textarea cols="200" id="message_body" name="message_body" style="height:300px;"><?php echo str_replace( "<br />", "", $AppUI->___((($message_id == 0) and ($message_parent != -1)) ? "\n>"  .  $last_message_info['message_body'] . "\n" : $message_info['message_body']) );   ?> 
</textarea>

<INPUT class="button" type=submit name="submit" value="Send" onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('message_body').saveContent();">
```

php section in textarea is taken from previous textArea field because I am editing already existing project.

There how looks mine text edited with niceEditor:
[image]

And how it looks when I post it:
[image]

In my opinion I need somehow to decode this text when I post it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with php function:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($printingValue);
```